# Extract multiple IClass values from a registry key

Tags: c++, c, windows-ce, driver

I am trying to get the `IClass` values from registry key using **RegQueryVaueEx** and convert them to GUID for my application. I could do that for `REG_SZ` size, however, I am trying to figure out a way to do the same for `IClass` values with REG_MULTI_SZ that have more than one  `IClass`. It doesn't seem to be straightforward as characters between the values are not consistent. Sometimes, each value is delimited by a COMMA, sometimes the IClass value is equated to `%b`. Is there a simple way to achieve what I am looking for? Please suggest.

Comment: What is an IClass value? Can you show a registry export with what you mean?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: `IClass` value is the unique ID (GUID) that a driver exposes to advertise the interface(s) that it supports.
Here is an example:
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\XXXX]
"IClass"=multi_sz:"{AA343A2A-E545-4AB2-9E6B-415567AFF865}",
"{8BB6723C-8234-33c8-A94A-6648AEEAA715}"`

@DeadMG: I am working in C.

Comment: Tagged more appropriately then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the best way to achieve this is to open the registry key of the driver with `RegOpenKeyEx` and use `RegEnumValue` to get the IClass values (by passing IClass value name as parameter) in a loop (do-while) until `RegEnumValue` fails.

Thanks all for the comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Searching my WinXP/64 registry, I find no "IClass" value.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that MULTI_SZ is a list of nul-terminated strings with a size value; and that page has example code that "walks a REG_MULTI_SZ string."

Comment: This is for WinCE (please refer the tags). You can find more info on `IClass` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa447465.aspx).  I am trying to extract the IClass strings from the IClass data of REG_MULTI_SZ size.